# spinlock in Assembly confusion

Tags: assembly, process, operating-system, spinlock

trying to use spin lock method to schedule processes on Intel Galileo board, the documentation shows mutex_lock is a function like this;

```
    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------
  * mutex_lock(uint32 *lock)  --  Acquire a lock
  *------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
mutex_lock:

/* Save registers that will be modified */

pushl   %eax
pushl   %ebx
pushl   %ecx

movl    $1, %ebx    /* Place the "locked" value in ebx  */
movl    16(%esp), %ecx  /* Place the address of the lock in ecx */

spinloop:
movl    $0, %eax    /* Place the "unlocked" value in eax    */
lock    cmpxchg %ebx, (%ecx)  
/* Atomic compare-and-exchange: */
/* Compare eax with memory (%ecx)   */
/* if equal             */
/*  load %ebx in memory (%ecx), ZF=1*/
/* else                 */
/*  load memory in %eax, ZF=0   */

/* If ZF = 0, the mutex was locked, so continue the spin loop   */

jnz spinloop

/* We hold the lock now, so pop the saved registers and return  */
popl    %ecx
popl    %ebx
popl    %eax
ret
```

**1 why the variable uint32*lock in passed into the function, but is never used in the function?**

**2. is the code section begin with lock related to the *lock we passed into? if so, what does that mean?**

**3. Thanks to @wallyk, I understand why there is a 16(esp), however, I am still not sure how the pointer of lock is automatically put into that position, which part of code does that?**

Many thanks!

Comment: This is code from two decades ago, back when processors worked very differently.  Don't use it.  Never write your own, use the PAUSE instruction if you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 0):

1. The parameter `lock` is used in the instruction

   movl   16(%esp), %ecx

The parameter is at offset 16 from the top of the stack.  Notice the three `push` instructions at entry, and recall that a `call` instruction (which is how this code is meant to be activated) pushes the return EIP address.

There are better ways to code this in assembly, but this is one way which uses no structures.  It also would probably cause trouble if ported to a non-32-bit architecture without some tweaking.

2. No, the `lock` instruction is a x86 CPU instruction prefix which manages concurrent access among multiple CPUs (and cores) on the same memory system and associated caches.  In this case, it is making sure that `cmpxchg %ebx, (%ecx)`, which is a read/modify/write instruction, executes atomically regardless of what other cores, CPUs, and caches are doing to that memory location.

Comment: I am not sure if I get your point correctly, so from the top of the stack, EIP, value of eax, ebx, ecx, is pushed into. so leaving a offset of 16 for *lock.   But how the process works that the pointer of lock is put into 16(esp)?

Comment: @javarookie:  For it to work successfully, the address of the lock is pushed on the stack by the caller before calling the function.  The caller must also pop a value off the stack after return.